# I am trying to data from on website using scrapy but getting errors

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrap data from a website but getting error but data is also being scraped. first the data is being scraped and after that errors comes. please provide me with proper solution for this
https://puntadelcielo.com.mx/pages/our-stores this is the url
https://storelocator.apps.isenselabs.com/stores/getStoresData?shop=puntadelcielo-1658.myshopify.com&sa=0
this is the json response which you will get from network in inspect tab that json url contains all data which I required. when I crawl this data is scraped but got this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\prath\OneDrive\Desktop\demo\demo.py", line 13, in 
print("Store ID:", value['id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
import requests

# page url = 'https://puntadelcielo.com.mx/pages/our-stores'
# below is json url 
url = 'https://storelocator.apps.isenselabs.com/stores/getStoresData?shop=puntadelcielo-1658.myshopify.com&sa=0'

r = requests.get(url)

#print(r.status_code)
data = r.json()
#print(data)
for key, value in data.items():
    print("Store ID:", value['id'])
    print("Name:", value['name'])
    print("Address:", value['store_address'])
    print("Latitude:", value['latitude'])
    print("Longitude:", value['longitude'])
```

Comment: if someone negative down the question, pls put a comment so new users feel welcome and can fix the information you are looking!  Welcome Prathamesh, when you loop, try looping this way and you will get the result. `for each_record in data:
    print(data[each_record]['name'])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The [url in question](https://storelocator.apps.isenselabs.com/stores/getStoresData?shop=puntadelcielo-1658.myshopify.com&sa=0) returns nested dict. You are trying to get dict from one-level deep but all `items` on that level are not `dict` so you need to skip those which are not `dict`.

```
for value in data.values():
    if type(value) != dict:
        continue
    print("Store ID:", value['id'])
    print("Name:", value['name'])
    print("Address:", value['store_address'])
    print("Latitude:", value['latitude'])
    print("Longitude:", value['longitude'])
```

You can use copy the json to console of your browser or [codebeautify.org](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) to see the json more clearly.